# Return array keys and values

Tags: array

I am creating some options in the functions.php file. I created a function that gets input on the front end, puts the values into a new array and returns them to the front end. I am trying to figure out how to return the values like an associative array. For example, I want to the array to return like this

```
Array ( [dribble_id] => dribble [google_id] => google [facebook_id] => facebook [twitter_id] => twitter )
```

the below function returns them like so

```
 Array ( [0] => dribble [1] => google [2] => facebook [3] => twitter )
```

Here is the function that returns them

```
 function ritual_get_options()
{
   $arg_list = func_get_args();

    $options = array();
    foreach( $arg_list as $key => $value){
    $options[] = ot_get_option($value);
}
    return $options;
}
```

Do you now how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a Wordpress question but more PHP. To solve this problem, you need to use `$value` as your key as well plus `_id`

You can do something like this

```
$options[$value . '_id'] = ot_get_option($value);
```

**EDIT**

If you need `$key` to be the value of `id`, you can also try something like this

```
$options[$value . '_' . $key] = ot_get_option($value);
```

This will render something like

```
google_0 => google
google_1 => google
google_2 => google
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to make use of `$key` as `id` as well